# How to add a google autocomplete input inside of a vuetify dialog box

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

As the title states, Im looking to add a google autocomplete inside of a vuetify dialog box within vue.js. I have successfully added autocomplete to regular inputs on the page by using the mounted() function and attaching there(code below). However it seems that since the dialog box doesnt render until you click a button to launch it, using this.$refs and attaching an autocomplete to those inputs wont work. Ive also tried creating a function to attach after the dialog launches and it still does not work. Any insight appreciated.

The part that works:

```
mounted() {
   
    console.log(this.$refs)
    //creates google maps automcomplete on the address inputs. Gets the addresses and saves them as well as getting the lat and long from each and saving them
    for (let ref in this.$refs) {
      const options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' },
        fields: ['geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address'],
        strictBounds: false,
        types: ['address'],
      }
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        this.$refs[ref],
        options
      )
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        // selected place object, bring up info such as address & geo coords
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace()

        // gets the address and lat/long from the found address and saves them to be used later when actually creating the order
        if (ref == 'pickupAddress') {
          this.pickupAddress = `${place.formatted_address}`
          this.pickupPair = place.geometry.location
        } else {
          this.dropoffAddress = `${place.formatted_address}`
          this.dropoffPair = place.geometry.location
        }
      })
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('getOpenOrders')
  }
```

The dialog box

```
<v-row justify="center">
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            color="rgb(216, 52, 125)"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            style="margin-top: 10px"
            @click="addRefs"
          >
            Add a leg to an existing order
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Add a leg</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-container>
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Order ID*"
                    required
                    v-model="legId"
                    hint="Order ID of the order you want to add a leg to"
                    persistent-hint
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Leg Letter (a-z)*"
                    required
                    v-model="legLetter"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12">
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Leg Pickup Address*"
                    ref="legPickupAddress"
                    required
                    v-model="legPickup"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12">
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Leg Dropoff Address*"
                    ref="legDropoffAddress"
                    required
                    v-model="legDropoff"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-container>
            <small>*indicates required field</small>
            <v-alert
              class="v-alert"
              v-if="noLegFoundAlert"
              type="error"
              dismissible
              @click="noLegFoundAlert = !noLegFoundAlert"
            >
              No matching leg found, please enter another id or create a leg!
            </v-alert>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn text @click="dialog = false"> Close </v-btn>
            <v-btn text @click="addLeg"> Save </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-row>
```

and finally the addRefs function which DOES NOT WORK

```
async addRefs() {
      const options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' },
        fields: ['geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address'],
        strictBounds: false,
        types: ['address'],
      }
      var input = this.$refs['legPickupAddres']  //DOES NOT WORK DOESNT EXIST APPARENTLY!!!!!!
      const autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options)
      autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        // selected place object, bring up info such as address & geo coords
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace()
        // gets the address and lat/long from the found address and saves them to be used later when actually creating the order
        this.legPickup = `${place.formatted_address}`
      })
     
    }
```